# Slim form not passing array with image information

Tags: php, html, forms, file-upload, slim

So I have an html form and it is passing my picture(the actual name), but that is all I can get. It shows an error when I try to get the tmp_name or anything of that sort.

Also, I can only get the name of the file if my html form has no declared `enctype`.

HTML

```
<form action="{{ urlFor('account.profile.post') }}" method="post" autocomplete="off">
  <!-- OTHER TEXT INPUTS THAT OUTPUT PERFECTLY FINE -->
  <div class="form-group">
    <label for="propic">Profile picture</label>
    <input type="file" id="propic" name="propic">
  </div>
</form>
```

PHP

```
if($app->request->params('propic') != null) {
  $propic = $app->request->post('propic');
  $target_dir = "profs/$img_salt/";
  $target_file = $target_dir.$propic;
  $uploadOk = 1;
  $imageFileType = pathinfo($target_file, PATHINFO_EXTENSION);

  if (move_uploaded_file($propic["tmp_name"], $target_file)) {
    echo "The file ". basename( $propic["name"]). " has been uploaded.";
  } else {
    echo "Sorry, there was an error uploading your file.";
  }
}
```

Comment: What error are you getting?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to set the encoding type of the form to `multipart/form-data`:

```
<form action="{{ urlFor('account.profile.post') }}" method="post" autocomplete="off" enctype="multipart/form-data">
```

Without this encoding type, you won't be able to send files with that form.

And in your php, grab the file from files instead of post (not sure if the following code is the way to do it in the php framework you are using):

```
$propic = $app->request->files('propic');
```

Comment: When I add the enctype, I am unable to even get the filename. Currently, a vap_dump on `$propic` gives me the file name. When I add the enctype, it just returns null.

Comment: Thats because you are trying to retrieve the file from the post array, you have to get it from the files array ($_FILES)

Comment: Thank you! And I didn't see the ending of your answer when I was on my phone... I just used the $_FILES anyways though.